# What are all the security measures I should check over before deploying my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security

I want to make sure all security aspects of my application are covered. I know this will probably vary from application to application, but what are the general things you should make sure you are doing to prevent security breaches?

Answer (score 6):

Ryan Bates did a nice railscast on security that i have gotten something out of, you may want to check it out.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/178-seven-security-tips

Answer (score 3):

The official rails guide on security is really good:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Answer (score 2):

The site itself:

1. Are all the pages that required a login protected?
2. If an error occurs in the application does the user retrieve a general message instead of YSOD (asp mvc)
3. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

After that there are also external risk: 
A database-backup gets lost(stolen) , social engineers , angry co-workers , unpatched servers , ....

Comment: Also make sure that things that require a login also check authorization.

Answer (score 1):

attr_accessible, if you're not using it your models then that's a big security flaw as your users could effectively change any fields they want.